# Building program for other machines

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I created a simple program using Lazarus Ide Qt5. I'm using Kubuntu 20 right now. When I build and run it on another Linux distribuiton I get error:

Quote

> ./shortcutcreator: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Pas.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or direcctory.

How can I build it for other machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(lib)qt5pas is a C++->C flattening library for QT5. It is afaik available in the package repositories, simply install it on the receiving PC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I include qt5 execututables with my program without installing on user s computer? Or can I install it while user is offline? I have the link of [qt5pas](https://wiki.freepascal.org/CudaText#Linux_Qt5_build)

Comment: Yes, if you have sufficient privileges you can install via ssh and apt-get.  Distributing the library by hand also need privileges as it needs to be in a path searched by the dynamic linker. (and officially ldconfig must be run after, but afaik that is not critical under Linux). In my experience, pretending Linux is Windows never pays off.